# Solving equation involving complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

> (a) Find real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $(a+bi)^2 = -3-4i.$
>
> (b) Hence solve the equation: $z^2+i\sqrt{3}z+i = 0$.

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uUIX.png)

In the above question, I have solved part (a), with $a=\pm1$ and with $b=\mp2$, but I am not sure how to use this information to solve (b). I know they are relevant, because of the key word "hence," which dictates that I should use the information derived from part (a).

Please advise. Sorry in advance for any mistakes in labelling of the title and tags (I'm not very good at those, but am trying to improve on it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By completing the square, we have:

$$z^2+i\sqrt{3}z+i = 0$$

$$z^2+i\sqrt{3}z-\dfrac{3}{4} = -\dfrac{3}{4}-i$$

$$\left(z+\dfrac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2 = \dfrac{-3-4i}{4}$$

$$(2z+i\sqrt{3})^2 = -3-4i$$

Do you see how part (a) is relevant now?

Comment: How did you know that you should take 3/4 as it's not involved in the original equation? Apart from that, I understand the rest of it. Thanks.

Comment: In general, if you want to complete the square for $x^2+ax$, then you need to add $(a/2)^2$ to get $x^2+ax+(a/2)^2 = (x+a/2)^2$. Here, we need to add $(i\sqrt{3}/2)^2 = -3/4$.

Answer (score 0):

However, I arrived at this:

$z^2+i\sqrt(3)z+i=0$

$z^2+\frac{i\sqrt(3)z}{2}-\frac34+i=0$

Taking $-\frac34+i$ to the other side results in:

$z^2+\frac{i\sqrt(3)z}{2}=\frac34-i$

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @JimmyK4542, did I do something wrong here?

Comment: the second equation does not follow from the first.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $$(a+bi)^2=-3-4i$$
$$(a^2-b^2)+2iab=-3-4i$$
comparing real & imaginary parts, one should get $$a^2-b^2=-3\tag 1$$  $$2ab=-4\tag 2$$ 
solve (1) & (2) for the values of $a$ & $b$.

b) $$z^2+i\sqrt 3z+i=0$$
$$\left(z^2+2i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}z+\left(\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2\right)-\left(\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2+i=0$$
$$\left(z+\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2=-\frac{3}{4}-i=\frac{-3-4i}{4}$$
$$\left(2z+i\sqrt 3\right)^2=-3-4i$$

> **Alternative Method:** use quadratic formula to find the roots of $z^2+i\sqrt 3z+i=0$ as follows $$z^2+i\sqrt 3z+i=0$$
>   $$z=\frac{-i\sqrt 3\pm\sqrt{(-i\sqrt 3)^2-4(1)(i)}}{2(1)}=\frac{-i\sqrt 3\pm i\sqrt{3+4i}}{2}$$